# JavaScript remove signs on start and end of string

Tags: javascript

Anybody know, how can i remove signs (&&) with JavaScript on start and on the end of a string?

My string

```
&& value && value && value &&
```

or

```
&& value
```

or

```
value &&
```

I need string like this

```
value && value && value
```

or

```
value
```

Comment: I suggest you read or re-read a basic regexp tutorial. Then you will be able to solve problems like this yourself without having to post here. Any regexp intro will introduce you to the notion of "anchors", which match at the beginning or end of the string. You could start off by [reading this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Using_special_characters).

Comment: Possible Duplicate of [If text begins or ends with these characters, remove characters](//stackoverflow.com/q/35380077) and [Javascript Remove strings in beginning and end](//stackoverflow.com/q/19134860)

Comment: Do you want to remove only two ampersands, or two or more, or any ampersands including a single one at the beginning and end?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With regexp:

```
// To remove "&" at the beginning and at the end
"&& value && value && value &&".replace(/^&+|&+$/g, '')
   // To remove white spaces
   .trim();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `replace` to replace the `&&`

and `trim` to remove leading/starting white spaces

```js
var string = "&& value && value && value &&";

let replaced = string.replace(/(^&+)|(&+$)/g, "");

console.log(replaced.trim());
```

Comment: You don't really need the `(`capturing groups`)`…

Comment: @deceze It's just a habit to make things more readable. I do as a precaution mostly. Like how I'll bracket things in an `if` statement even if it isn't needed.

Comment: Why not do it all in one go with `/^&+ *| *&+$/`?

Answer (score -1):

Try this it will help you,

```js
var s="&& value && value && value &&";
var a=s.match(/[^&/]+/g).join('&&');
alert(a);
```

Comment: This does a lot more than *remove ampersands at the start or end*.